# Regex: 15 integers with a maximum of two decimals, excluding 0

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a custom validation with regex but cant find the right one.

15 integers max, 2 decimals max. 0 is not allowed.

Im usign this regex at this moment: `/^(?:\d{1,15}(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?|[.,]\d{1,2})$/`

but that one stills allows a 0

Valid cases:

- 0,01
- 123,1
- 1234,50
- 123456789012345,20

invalid cases:

- 0
- -1
- 13,421
- 123,223
- 1234567890123456

Comment: Is there a regex you tried and didn't work? If so then please add a relevant code snippet

Comment: Im sorry, i forgot to put my old regex. Im using this at this moment:

 /^(?:\d{1,15}(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?|[.,]\d{1,2})$/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below pattern matches a digit between 1 and 15 times, followed by an optional group comprising a comma then either one or two digits. The pattern matches the entire string (from start to end) due to the anchors. It begins with a negative lookahead to ensure the entire string is not just the character "0".

`(?!^0$)^\d{1,15}(?:,\d{1,2})?$`

It matches all valid cases and no invalid cases from your question.

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/kB8jXt/1

Comment: good regex! it almost works for me, i cant allow 0 to be valid, cant match that case. I need to exclude 0

Im using this old regex right now but stills dont work 

/^(?:\d{1,15}(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?|[.,]\d{1,2})$/

Comment: See edit, I use a negative lookahead.